# Can someone help me with this question

Tags: gas

Is there any way at all i can send crypto from wallet a to wallet b and pre pay the gas or pay the gas with a diffent address. for example on the tron chain is ther any way i can send trc20 usdt to another account without using trx form gas, maybe use usdt trc20 for gas ???

Answer (score 0):

there is no way, you could set a contract to burn some usdt into gas in order to pay transaction fees, but that contract will use gas to run so...
You always need gas in order to send a transaction.
The only way to do it is off-chain